# Iterate over an array of objects with object having multiple properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to iterate over the following:

```
state = {
 products : [
  {
   x : "sd",
   y : "fdg"
  },  {
   x : "sdx",
   y : "fdgx"
  }
 ]
}
```

I need to iterate over the above products array and inside object to create:

```
<tr><td>sd</td><td>fdg</td></tr>
```

I tried using :

```
{
    this.state.products.map(function(prod) { 

        return <tr><td>{prod.x}</td><td>{prod.y}</td></tr>;
    })
}
```

but get multiple errors and prod being undefined.

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated code

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that logic elsewhere in your component is mutating the state, which in turn may be the root cause of the error thrown during rendering.

Be sure to check that the `products` array is consistently defined in your components `state`, and that the items in that array are defined.

One solution here might be to take a more defensive approach to rendering your table row elements, by doing the following:

```
{
    Array.isArray(this.state.products) && this.state.products
    .filter(product => !!product)
    .map(product => { 

        return <tr><td>{product.x}</td><td>{product.y}</td></tr>;
    })
}
```

Here, the rendering logic asserts that `this.state.products` is the expected array type via `Array.isArray()`. Addtionally, the logic ensures any prop being rendered is defined by first filtering out any undefined `prop` items via this line:

```
filter(product => !!product)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the return statement is an HTML code which is causing the problem whereas you can encode the code into a string and the DOM will treat it as HTML code

```
this.state.products.map(function(prod){  return "<tr><td>"+prod.x+"</td><td>"+prod.y +"</td> </tr>" }).
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add that in one variable return as below:

```
const prod = this.state.products.map(function(prod) { 
    return <tr><td>{prod.x}</td><td>{prod.y}</td></tr>;
});
```

Use the variable inside render lifecycle as below.

```
{prod}
```

Here is the working code attached in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/varit05/n5u2wwjg/239547/)

Hope this helps!